# lodsb output on 2 different machines with 2 different results

Tags: assembly, bootloader, bios, low-level

I have been currently playing around with asm and low-level stuff like printing chars on the screen with no OS, just via bios interrupt calls.

my code works with qemu (seabios), but when I write my bootsector to usb, I get two different results on two different machines

The following code just calls the bios interrupt (0x10) to print out a string (resp. characters in a loop) with tty-output function (0x0e).

It works on qemu and on my laptop (output on the screen: "12341234567"). however when I am using my desktop-pc the output on the screen is... nothing. I just get a black screen with a blinking _ (it looks like it comes from the tty function, and it only didn't print any characters)

Some informations on my systems:

Emulation with "qemu-system-x86_64 /dev/sdb" on my Laptop

Laptop: Intel Atom n270 (32-bit, Phoenix Bios)

Desktop-PC: AMD Phenom II x6 1090t (64-bit, AMI Bios v1.17)

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bp, 0xffff ; set stack location
mov sp, bp

mov ax, cs ; store cs in ds
mov ds, as

cld
mov si, MSG_TEST
call prnt

jmp $ ; prevent cpu from executing arbitrary bytes after this stuff aka hang

prnt:
  push ax
  push bx
  push si

  mov bh, 0
  _test_loop:
     lodsb
     cmp al, 0
     je _test_end

     mov ah, 0x0e
     int 0x10
     jmp _test_loop

_test_end:
    pop si
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret

MSG_TEST db "12341234567", 0

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 ; pad out (512 bytes)
dw 0xaa55 ; magic number bootable
```

I don't think this issue has something to do with 32/64 bit compatibility since in this stage I am still in 16-bit realmode.

Comment: `mov ds, as` a typo? should be `mov ds, ax`

Comment: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) "A 64-bit UEFI firmware implementation can only load a 64-bit UEFI operating system boot loader or kernel. For backwards compatibility, most of the UEFI firmware implementations on PC-class machines also support booting in legacy BIOS mode from MBR-partitioned disks, through the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) which provides legacy BIOS compatibility. In that scenario, booting is performed in the same way as on legacy BIOS-based systems, by ignoring the partition table and relying on the content of a boot sector."

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1.**
Function 0x0e requires active video mode page in BH register. By default it is 0.
`mov bh, 0` before `_test_loop:` should solve the issue.
**Option 2.**
BIOS loads bootcode at address 0x07c0:0 instead of 0:0x7c00. In this case data and code segments should differ. ds:si just points to wrong location
**Option 3.**
PC boots in graphics mode, in this case BL should contain character color: `mov bx, 7`
**Option 4**
Stack alignment issue: 0xffff is a bad offset. It should be even. For example, 0xfffe.
**Option 5**
stack segment issue. `ss` should be initialized, too

What happens if you try

```
  org 0x7c00

  xor cx, cx
  mov ss, cx
  mov sp, 0x7bfe
  mov ds, cx
  mov es, cx
  mov si, text
  call print
  jmp $

print:
  ;
  ; display null-terminated ascii string in teletype mode
  ; at current cursor position
  ;
  ; input:
  ;   ds:si     - pointer to string
  ;
  mov bh, 0
  mov ah, 0x0e
  lodsb
  test al, al
  jz short $+6
  int 0x10
  jmp short $-7
  ret
```

Comment: it didnt solve the problem. I have the same effects (emulator/laptop working, but not on pc). Edited my post with your suggestions though, and I additionally push bx on the stack and pop it off, right after mov bh, 0 just in case

Comment: unfortunately i had no success. option2: i changed `[org 0x7c00]
` to `[org 0]` and added `jmp 0x7c00:bootsector_entry`
`bootsector_entry:` (if that is what you meant). option 5: I added `mov ax, 0` and `mov ss, ax`

Comment: sorry have no more ideas atm. I usually check if a routine enters or exits correctly by writing a char directly to video memory. `mov ax, 0xb800 / mov es, ax / mov [es:0], byte '!'` you could try it on enter to and exit from `prnt` to see if it's executed at all

Comment: Ok this is strange now: I added `mov ax, 0xb800 / mov es, ax / mov [es:0], byte '!'` between `mov si, MSG_TEST` and `call prnt`, added `[org 0x7c00] / jmp 0x0000:bootsector_entry / bootsector_entry:`  and now it shows the string. The '!' isn't beeing displayed though... I have no idea why the program behaves like that. Anyway thanks for your time and your help. It was very useful.

Comment: tried the code you added in your answer and it partially works, it outputs 'bdfhbdfhj' although I expected to print '12341234567', but it looks like encoding issues b->1, d->2.